# Disable QGIS from rendering on start up

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.18

Is it possible to set a default so that on opening a QGIS file it doesn't attempt to render?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under Settings -> options -> Rendering, you can alter the rendering behavior.

By disabling the option "By default new layers added to the map should be displayed" you prevent QGIS from rendering the file (see image)

[image]